# Iniciante em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de checar varias variáveis de uma vez. Veja o que tentei:

Exemplo

```
    nota1 = 10
    nota2 = 20
    nota3 = 30

for i in (1, 2, 3)
    if nota{i} == 0 
    print('É zero')
```

No caso, são muitas variáveis então seria inviável escrever uma a uma. Existe alguma solução?

Comment: Você precisa saber se uma das variáveis é zero?

Comment: Oi Lucas, poderia dar mais informações sobre o que você precisa fazer? não deu pra entender muito bem. Explique um pouco melhor o seu problema

Comment: Vc quer saber se a nota 0 esta inserida? Faça uma lista com as notas e depois use o condicional if junto com o in.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize um array:

```
notas = [10, 20, 30]
for nota in notas:
    if nota == 0:
        print("É zero")
```

Comment: Não era mais simples fazer `0 in notas`?

Comment: acho que pra esse caso não. creio que seja só um exemplo o print. O objetivo real seja fazer algo com a nota que é 0, e não apenas verificar se existe uma ou não

Answer (score -1):

uma alternativa não muito simples, mas que funciona:

```
notas = ['10','20','30','40','0','0']
sem_zeros = [n for n in notas if n != '0']
for nota in sem_zeros:
    print(int(nota))
```